# TypeORM hooks before save with access to the repository

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

Does anyone have a smart solution to check if the user is allowed to change the entity values. Something like a hook before .save()? The default entity hooks do not have access to the repo. I want the user to be able to update an entity only if the userid matches.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can define a custom method `saveAsUser(user)` which checks if the user is allowed to make changes and then calls `save()` accordingly

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ranjan_purbey sounds good. Do you have a working example for that?

Comment: Thanks @ErangaHeshan but I cant use hooks because they cant interrupt saving. Also they only have access to the repo via entityMananger wich makes it hard to find the right repo.